# Is it possible to ask your users to clear their HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) for your site?

Tags: http, browser-cache

If you turn on HSTS for your website with a large lifetime but later decide to turn it off (due to issues with third party software for instance) is it possible to warn users to clear their 'HSTS cache'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To turn off HSTS for your server send a header of

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
```

Comment: how to find this in  my server?