# Request Safari web client to disregard HSTS

Tags: macos, https, safari, http-headers, hsts

I've taken over a site that previously used HSTS, but because of some iframes I need to embed, I need to disable it.  I'm able to intelligently redirect from one protocol to the other, but Safari, in particular, doesn't want to disregard its HSTS cache.

In this question ([Is it possible to ask your users to clear their HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) for your site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707978/is-it-possible-to-ask-your-users-to-clear-their-http-strict-transport-security)) and on other sites, I've seen that I can request browsers to remove my site from their HSTS cache by sending the following header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
```

However, Safari doesn't seem to care about that.  On a coworker's computer, which has the site in its HSTS cache, receiving that header is not preventing it from automatically redirecting to https.

Anyone know a way to tell Safari to disregard HSTS?

Comment: Is it possible that it was previously being sent with a "preload"? In Chrome's case, this would essentially make it part of feeds into Chrome from Google's servers. Safari may do something similar.

Comment: Ssllabs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) gives s nice easy way of checking all preload lists. It doesn't have one for Safari but at least can check others (which safari might still use). Not to say it didn't used to be in preload list and now removed though.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaDeWald. It is possible, and seems logical.

Comment: @BazzaDP, it would seem logical that it could be on those lists, but, interestingly, it's not.  In any case, if it were, it seems like a long path forward to be removed (which is discouraged).  But since, it's not, I'm pretty much at a loss on how to tell safari to disregard.

Answer (score 0):

It could be set on the top level domain.

So if you are looking at www.example.com then maybe the policy has been published from example.com with includeSubDomains option so it affects all subdomains (including www subdomain).

If so the answer is similar. Publish this header from the base domain and make sure you visit the base domain (even if it just redirects to main domain).

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
```

Also check the preload lists for the base domain.

Would also be worth looking through web config and any scripts or dynamic parts of the website (e.g. PHP, Java Servlets... Etc.) to make sure something is not still setting this when you visit a certain page for example.

Comment: I actually *was* checking the top level domain.  Our site is (and has been) always served from example.com (not www.example.com).  Good idea looking at all the served assets.  I haven't checked that yet.